# How many molecules are there typically in items made of plastics?

Tags: polymers

In objects made of plastic (and other polymers), how many molecules would one generally expect to find?

Intuitively, it seems like, say, a plastic shopping bag or PET bottle couldn't be a single molecule, but on the other hand, that's one of the strengths of polymers.

So the question is, I suppose, do items made of plastic consist of a single molecule, or many molecules fused together by way of glues or mechanical action?

**Edit:** Following a comment, I realise that the core of my question could be clearer, so here's an alternate phrasing:

If I chose an atom in a typical plastic object and gave it a colour, and then gave every atom connected to it by way of covalent bonds the same colour by flood fill, and then chose a colourless atom in the object and repeated the process until no more colourless atoms existed in the object, how many colours would a typical plastic object have?

Comment: Most plastic items are composed of many molecules. If you stretch a plastic bag, the molecules line up beside each other (like uncooked spaghetti). Since the bag is not one molecule thick or wide, there must be a lot of molecules. OTOH, under the right conditions the rubber in a tire could be one molecule.

Comment: @LDC3 "[A] bag is not one molecule thick or wide[.]"? Molecules come in a wide variety of thicknesses and widths, which is why I'm asking. Although I guess my question could do with a bit of clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The short answer is a very large number and far more than you could reasonably count**

Polymerization reactions typically produce very large molecules but not so large that a single molecule would make up as much material as a whole plastic bag or item of any significant size. [This source](http://nzic.org.nz/ChemProcesses/polymers/10J.pdf) on LDPE tells us that the typical molecular weight of the industrial product is 90,000 (some polymers are much bigger than this).

For non-chemists molecular weights are (simplifying slightly) the weight relative to a single hydrogen atom. Carbon is 12 on this scale and ethylene (the monomer from which the plastic is made which consists of 2 carbons and 4 hydrogens) is 32. This mean that a typical molecule of the plastic is (crudely) made from a little under 3,000 ethylene molecules. The other fact you need to know is that there are about 6 x 10<sup>23</sup> hydrogen atoms in a gramme of hydrogen (see the [wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) of Avogadro's number). Simple mathematics tells us that a gramme of LDPE will contain roughly 6.7 x 10<sup>18</sup> molecules so that is the order of the number in small plastic item which, I expect, weighs just a few grammes.

So, the bottom line is that even in a small plastic item consisting of a long chain polymer (LDPE is relatively short but other polymers might have chains 10-100 times more at most) there will be something like 10<sup>16</sup> to 10<sup>18</sup> molecules of polymer, which is a lot.

Comment: Very heavily cross-linked polymers could conceivably create single molecules of macroscopic size. As LDC3 mentions, vulcanised rubber is one possibility. I think the molar mass range for polymers can go from anywhere between some $\rm{10^3\ g\ mol^{-1}}$ for oligomers to  $\rm{10^{25}\ g\ mol^{-1}}$ and beyond.

Comment: There is nothing very useful or well defined between 10000 kg/mol and one network molecule for the whole object.

Answer (score 3):

Some plastics have their molecular weight (m.w.) specified, e.g. [polyethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) and [ultra-high-molecular-weight polyethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-molecular-weight_polyethylene). Knowing the type of plastic, and therefore its m.w., and the mass of the object, using [Avogadro's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), you should be able to calculate how many molecules there are.

Measuring a low-density polyethylene sandwich bag would be a convenient place to start.